# Error configuring iScroll angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iscroll

Hi i'm trying to configure with an angular directive [iscroll](http://iscrolljs.com/).
on angularjs and it doesn't scroll so i tried just as a single page to see how it works and it doesn't scroll again, i don't understand why, here is the example code

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/iscroll/build/iscroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var myScroll;
 function loaded() {
        console.log("partita loaded");
     myScroll = new IScroll("#wrapper");
 }
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app"  onload="loaded()"> 
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
          <!-- a lot of elements -->
</ul>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll ?
Also you should put your iscroll within a directive in the angular lifecycle. Atm your IScroll is in a different area than your angular app

Comment: i've tried making a directive but it doesn't work so i've added directly in an empty page and the result was the same

Comment: Resolved the problem was the PreventDefault option of iscroll